# PhpStorm warning - Cannot resolve directory 'https'

Tags: css, phpstorm

How can I solve (Cannot resolve directory 'https' warning) when I use URL in CSS?

[image: URL warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-56089](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-56089/CSS-Avoid-file-reference-errors-in-httpdata-URLs-in-webpack-projects), please follow it for updates

Please see the comments in the youtrack ticket for possible workarounds